How can, I go about pulling 5 different enpoints as one
I was trying to get Angular Fire to pull a list from 5 different entries in RTDB.
The data looks like this
{
    "things": {
        "one" : [],
        "two" : [],
        "three" : []
    }
}

My regular Firebase RTDB calls all contain a switchmap because I need the calls to be dynamic. No difference here.
this.a_s.thing$ = this.a_s.x$.pipe(switchMap((x) => {
      return this.db.list('things/'+x).valueChanges();   
}));

this.a_s.thing$.subscribe({next:(value) => {}
});

How can I alter this code to ensure that the values contained in arr = ['one', 'three'] all gets called and returned in a multi-array. Say, instead of value[]. Length = 1, I wanted the value array to return something like this value = [ [], [] ].
